# How to import a module inside the Deno REPL?

Tags: deno

Attempting to import a module in the Deno REPL results in the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at evaluate (rt/40_repl.js:60:36)
    at replLoop (rt/40_repl.js:160:15)
```

I use the Node REPL to quickly test out code, almost on a daily basis. The ability to import external code without writing a script or dealing with temporary files is a huge convenience.

Why can't Deno use import statements outside of a module? Is it even possible to use external code in the Deno REPL?

Comment: See https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1285

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting with [v1.4.3](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.4.3), you can use [top-level `await` in the REPL](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/7784) to dynamically `import` modules:

```
> const path = await import("https://deno.land/std@0.73.0/path/mod.ts")
> path.basename("/my/path/name")
"name"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you also try to use `import a from "a"` in Node REPL, it will also throw the same error. Only `require` can be directly used to import modules in Node REPL.

For Deno, there is no built-in CommonJS loader. Therefore it does not even provide `require` for you to load stuff synchronously.

The technical reason of why static import cannot be used in REPL is that REPL is actually a script evaluation tool: instead of compiling what you write into an ES Module, they are treated as plain scripts and directly fed into the engine, in the way similar to `<script>` in the browser without turning on the `type="module"`. (ES modules with static imports have the semantics of asynchronously loading dependencies and determining the "shape" of a module without even actually running it.)

To import modules in Deno REPL, you can use dynamic `import()`. Personally I sometimes do the following (loading is usually fast enough such that you will pretty much have `mod` value set before you continue using the mod in REPL):

```js
$ deno
> let mod; import("./mod.ts").then(m => mod = m)
Promise { <pending> }
Check file:///[blah]/mod.ts
> mod
Module { a: 1, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module" }
```